# Word 2016 mail merge missing 15.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, mailmerge

When running an existing mail merge I receive an error in one of my machines: Class not registered

No real indication of what is not register

The only thing I can find different between working and non-working machines is in the Data Link Providers. in the non-working machines I am missing 'Microsoft Office 15.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider'.

I assume these documents were created using this provider and my trouble machines does not have it.

Any tips for how to get it?

Thanks!

Comment: In VBA IDE under Tools \ References select version 16.0. Office 15.0 is MS Office 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install the Access 2013 Runtime. This made 'Microsoft Office 15.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider' available in Word 2016. Although the default application to launch .ACCDB became the runtime, so I needed to change the default back to 2016.

Here's a link to the 2013 Runtime: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358